# iOS Gamekit Max Peer-to-Peer Size

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, p2p, gamekit

In looking at the Gamekit documentation I see that the max Client/Server size for a game is 16.  Is this the same as the size for peer-to-peer?  Would it be possible for a peer to be in multiple games at once to make this size bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I had the same question and found the answer in Apple's docs.

**The maximum size of a client-server game is 16 players.**

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html

Comment: The documentation is unclear if the limit of 16 applies to the client-server version, or to that AND the peer-to-peer version.  Is peer-to-peer just two client-server schemes put together, or is the peer-to-peer version excepted from the limitation?